# kFIREventViewItem Event log parameters does not show up in Firebase Console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics

I tried this code to test `Firebase` analytics

```
FIRAnalytics.setUserID(username)
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName(kFIREventViewItem, parameters:
[kFIRParameterItemID: productId, kFIRParameterItemName: productName,
kFIRParameterItemCategory:"Fashion"])
```

After waiting for several hours (maybe 3-4 hours), my `Firebase` console show view_item ,but when I go to it`s detail, none of those parameters show up in`Firebase` console

i have enable debug logging for iOS and i see the params is sent.

My expected result is like this
[image]
I want to see the chart based based on my user and product which he/she tap to view (not add_cart or buy yet), what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, We cloudn't see all parameters at console even if default event like "kFIREventViewItem". It is in development.

you can see parameter at BigQuery.